# Backbone event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to get an event to fire in a view but it doesn't seem to be triggering.  This view runs from within another view, so not sure if the event is not being setup properly.

```
var ListRow = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    events:
    {
        'click .button.delete': 'destroy'
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'remove');
    },

    render: function()
    {
        this.el = _.template($('#tpl-sTableList_' + key + 'Row').html());

        return this;
    },


    destroy: function()
    {
        console.log('remove')
    }
});
```

Comment: in here `this.el = _.template($('#tpl-sTableList_' + key + 'Row').html());` where does **Key** come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting your `this.el`, what you want to do instead is

```
render: function ()
{
    var tpl = _.template($('#tpl-sTableList_' + key + 'Row').html());
    this.$el.empty().html(tpl);
    // or if you prefer the old way
    // $(this.el).empty().html(tpl);
    return this;
},
```

if that's causing you problems with your DOM representation having an extra wrapped element around it try this instead:

```
render: function ()
{
    var tpl = _.template($('#tpl-sTableList_' + key + 'Row').html());
    this.setElement(tpl, true); // this is a Backbone helper 
    return this;
},
```

Comment: And [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) exists specifically for those cases where you want to replace `this.el` and make sure that all the internals (such as [`this.$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-$el) and [the events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents)) are properly reset.

Comment: okay, the first part makes sense to me, the elements did not attach because it was just a string and not an element at that point.  Which brings me to the second point, there is a div wrapping my template, which normally would be fine, but since I'm appending tr to a table it's breaking.  This setElement is giving me a "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" error, also if I do a `console.log(this.el)` right after the `setElement` line, it shows the `Document` object?

Comment: okay was just missing the brackets for tpl(), works now, thanks!